# Mongodb How can I see if all elements of a field are contained in a superset

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, subset

I have a defined collection in Mongo that is a list of "supported" features.  In order for an item from another collection to be considered "compatible", I need to take that item's list of features and see if all of them are in the given list.  I have queried the supported features collection for the list of features already and I have them in a list.

For example, my list contains `[A, B, C, D, E]`
If my item has `[A, B]`, it should be returned, but if it has `[A, B, F]`, it should not.  The [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator states:

> "If the field holds an array, then the $in operator selects the
>   documents whose field holds an array that contains **at least one**
>   element that matches a value in the specified array"

The [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator states:

> "The $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is
>   an array that contains all the specified elements."

My problem is that the item doesn't have the full set of features for the $all command, and I don't want it to match on a single element for the $in command.  My query looks something like this (because I have already retrieved the list of compatible functions from the *functions* collection):

```
db.myColl.find({"compatibility": {"$in": ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]}})
```

or

```
db.myColl.find({"compatibility": {"$all": ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]}})
```

what I think I need is something that effectively reverses the query and says something like this (I know it's not valid, I'm just trying to make a point):

```
db.myColl.find({["A","B","C","D","E","F"]: {"$all": "compatibility"}})
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think it will be a lot easier if you share some schema information with concrete examples - you mention multiple collections but don't show schemas for either, and your examples don't match (first example compares a list (from where?) of [A,B,C,D,E] vs [A,B] and [A,B,F], second example is [A,B,C,D,E,F] against something else. I'd give concrete example documents and examples of where you want it to match and not match.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if every element in array matches condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595023/check-if-every-element-in-array-matches-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a very similar issue and found the solution:

```
db.myColl.find({"compatibility":{$not:{$elemMatch:{$nin:["A","B","C","D","E","F"]}}}})
```

While I'm not an expert in mongodb, it seems like they should add a primitive for this operation.

Good luck!

Comment: That did it - thanks!  Sorry if I duplicated another question.  I swear I searched for every term I could think of to represent the problem and could never get a satisfactory result!