# mongo find documents where at least one item from an array is not in the other

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this problem in mongo where I would like to make a query (regular mongo query, using the terminal) to find all the documents where a field is either empty, or has at least one value which does not match an array of regexes.

My documents have the following pattern:

```
{
  "id": "20",
  "array": ["abc123", "abc456", "def123", "ghi123"]
}
```

and

```
{
  "id": "21",
  "array": ["abc123", "abc456", "def123"]
}
```

My array to match them with would look like something like this:

```
[new RegExp(abc), new RegExp(def)]
```

The result of the query should be only the first document, as this one contains "ghi123", which doesn't match against any regex in the array.

I know there are operators like $all, $elementMatch, $in etc to build this query, but so far, I haven't found the right solution, and I've been stuck for quite a while... I found other StackOverflow pages that I found useful and might lead to the right answer, but I haven't been able to apply it to my problem yet. This one seemed the most useful:

[Check if every element in array matches condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595023/check-if-every-element-in-array-matches-condition)

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a regex problem as all the logic can be handled there:

```js
db.collection.find({ "array": /^(?!abc|def)/ })
```

This is just basically a negative assertion that the element being tested matches either condition separated by `|` which means **or**.

Since the first document is the only one that has an array element that would not meet the condition then it is the only case that will evaluate true here.

Regular expressions are generally constructed from a base "string" so considering the following representation of a "list" this should not be hard to follow:

```js
var args = ["abc","def"];

var exp = "^(?!" + args.join("|") + ")";
db.collection.find({ "array": new Regexp(exp) });
```

Or even:

```js
var args = ["abc","def"];
var inclause = { "$in": [ ] };

inclause["$in"] = args.map(function(arg) {
    return new Regexp( "^(?" + arg + ")" );
});

db.collection.find({ "array": inclause });
```

But the first form should generally be more efficient.

Comment: How would I negate an array of RegExp()'s then? Because my code will generate this regex list dynamically, so I have a list like you can see above.

Comment: @pidgey You can alternately repeat each indvidual term in an `$in` operator or even an `$or` operator which is a bit more explicit for m as `$in`. But as I said, a regex is basically constructed from a "string" as a feeding construct (especially if using `RegExp` as a constructor), so it is not a difficult task to join elements with a "|" pipe in concatenation. Using that raw regex form turns out to be a bit more efficient. Especially when you anchor "^" at the begining of the string, which allows very efficient index use.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following... are you suggesting something like this:

db.collection.find({
  'array': {
    '$in':[{'$not':new RegExp("abc")}, {'$not':new RegExp("def")}]
  }
})

Comment: @pidgey No. And don't pay that much attention to the other responses because they are wrong. Added more information to show basic construction for either case.

Comment: Is it a problem that my actual data contains chars like /, : and ~? because I get an empty collection as return, but there should be matches. I had a similar problem before

Comment: @pidgey It makes it very hard for everyone if you cannot present a data sample in your question that does not really match what you are asking. Yes you need to escape special characters in regular expressions. But not sure if that is even what you are asking. As a rule, we answer the "question you asked" and not additional questions in comments. The code I gave produces the correct match from the data you gave in the question you asked. If you have other questions then it is best to post them as other questions so we can really see what you are actually asking.

Comment: my apologies, I'm fairly new to this... sample data would be for example new RegExp("cpe:/o:microsoft"). Would you rather have me update my question?

Comment: @pidgey It would be better to submit a "new question" asking what you really want to do. But mostly if you read the answer and the comments and realized that it answers exactly the question that you asked. Changing what you are asking after receiving an answer will not win you over many friends. You escape reserved characters with "\". If you still don't understand then ask another question. But the question you asked here is answered.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and the answer. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @pidgey Then may I then ask "why have you not accepted the answer" when it clearly produces the result you asked for in your question originally? If you have other questions then post new questions. If the question you asked was answered correctly then you accept it. Common courtesy.

Comment: My apologies, I thought voting up was all I had to do... As I said, I'm fairly new to this. Thanks for letting me know