# MongoDB Query for subset in superset with or

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document "item" with the structure:

```
{
    "name": String,
    "parts": [
        {
        "alternate_names": Array,
        "size": String,
        "type": String
        }
    ]
}
```

E.g.

```
{
    "name": Plane,
    "parts": [
        {
        "alternate_names": ['wing', 'fin'],
        "size": 'Large',
        "type": 'Aero'
        },
        {
        "alternate_names": ['engine', 'motor'],
        "size": 'Medium',
        "type": 'Power'
        },
    ]
}
```

A query for parts.alternate_names: ["wing", "motor"] should return this document.
A query for parts.alternate_names: ["wing"] should not.

"alternate_names" is a list of possible names for a particular part.

Each item will have multiple parts. I want to create a query specifying the names of the parts that I have, and get back all the items I can make with those parts. To be able to make the item, I need to have all of the parts, but only one of the names from the "alternate_names" list for each part.

The closest I have managed to get is with the query:

```
{"parts.alternate_names": {
    "$not": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "$nin": ["part1", "part2", "part3", "part4"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it will only match if all the alternate_names for each part are specified, and not just one.

Is the only way to do this something like suggested here: [Check if every element in array matches condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595023/check-if-every-element-in-array-matches-condition)

Comment: Not sure if you are not being clear here bu `$in` will match just one.

Comment: @NeilLunn No, that would only work if there was only one part. Parts is an array, and all parts need to be included. That is where the complexity comes from.

Comment: Here is the confusing part of your question for me. "..all parts need to be included.." but also "..but only one of the 'alternate_names' list for each part..". So is "parts" actually meant to be made up of more than just objects with an "alternate_names" key? Otherwise the two terms conflict. This should be basic query logic without further computation, but your example does not seem as clear as it could be.

Comment: @NeilLunn is this clearer now?

Comment: I see it, but it's not a good structure. What you seem to be saying is that "parts" as an array has both elements as a plain string or either an object with a key that contains an array. What you want is all of the strings to be present "and" something/anything in the "alternate" list, but at least one match. Right? I actually would have expected some "parent/child" rel between a part name and an alternate name. The more you can say then the clearer it is.

Answer (score 2):

### Original Question Solution

---

From the document structure you describe, then you would ultimately have data like this:

```js
{
    "parts" : [
        {
           "alt_names" : [
                    "sizeo",
                    "bill"
            ]
        },
        "size",
        "type"
    ]
}
```

Whatever the actual arguments are, but this is just a standard **and** condition using both [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) and [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operators on the respective arrays:

```js
db.collection.find({ 
    "parts": { "$all": ["size","type"] },
    "parts.alt_names": { "$in": ["sizeo","sizeb"] } 
})
```

So the `$all` operator makes sure that all the specified elements in the conditions are present in the outer array, and the `$in` operator looks at the specific field.

Yes this is a basic query and yes it can use an index on the respective field values. The catch is that this cannot be a compound index due to the complexity level of indexing two "multi-key" values in the one index.

It sounds like you want the index on the outer array value, and then let the remaining brute force filtering to happen on the values in the remaining inner elements after the results have been reduced.

---

### Current Question solution

---

With a document like this:

```js
{
    "name" : "Plane",
    "parts" : [
            {
                    "alternate_names" : [
                            "wing",
                            "fin"
                    ],
                    "size" : "Large",
                    "type" : "Aero"
            },
            {
                    "alternate_names" : [
                            "engine",
                            "motor"
                    ],
                    "size" : "Medium",
                    "type" : "Power"
            }
    ],
}
```

The inner arrays need to be tested for the matches to the elements but your important condition here is that the outer array they belong to needs to contain a positive match for every element in the document.

An **`$all`** query argument will allow the selection of documents where all of the required array members are present. That narrows things down, but what is needed is a logical evaluation of the match within all elements. This is what the **`$allElementsTrue`** set operator of the aggregation framework can do.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "parts.alternate_names": { 
      "$all": [ "wing","motor" ],
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "parts": 1,
      "matched": {
        "$allElementsTrue": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": "$parts",
            "as": "p",
            "in": { "$anyElementTrue": { "$map": {
              "input": "$$p.alternate_names",
              "as": "a",
              "in": {
                "$or": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$$a", "wing" ] },
                   { "$eq": [ "$$a", "motor" ] }
                ]
              }                   
            }}}
          }}
        ]
      }
  }},
  { "$match": { "matched": true } }
])
```

The **`$map`** operator allows each array element to be inspected and have a condition evaluated on it, returning the results as an array of equal length but replacing each member with the result of the evaluation.

Within the iteration of the outer array there needs to be a similar `$map` operation to test whether those elements meet the list of words you want to match. So the same conditions in the query list are added as array elements to the **`$or`** operation. This does an equality match looking for either of the terms on any array element.

The results of that inner look at sent to **`$anyElementTrue`**. This is fine because it would be true here for any match in "alternate_names" to return positive in it's place. This narrows down the logical evaluation of this field in the outer array down to a singular `true|false` result per outer array member.

This effectively turns the "names" array into a list of `true|false` conditions depending on what was returned from evaluation of the inner array. Which comes to the overall objective that all of those conditions are `true`, and hence **`$allElementsTrue`** can then evaluate that array to determine that all elements are indeed `true`.

Comment: Perhaps I was still not clear enough. I have added a clearer example for you.

Comment: @user3524100 Do you now see what I placed the data structure you asked for in your question in the answer. I also asked you about it immediately after your edit. Changing data leads to totally different answers. Perhaps we should all come back in a week when you are sure about the question you are asking. The answer to your edits is pretty much the same, just a little longer winded.

Comment: @BatScream Understand perfectly with my initial example. But I understand that some people have difficulty understanding things that are explained to them, that is why I added more detail for you as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a more strict match than simply using `$nin`.

You could aggregate the result as below:

- `Match` all the items which contain at least one part that we are
  searching for.
- `Project` the number of parts in each item, which will be later used.
- `Unwind` the parts array.
- `Project` a temporary field which holds the the complete set of aliases
  for each part.
- Now `unwind` the alias names for each part.
- `Match` those documents which have the alias name we are looking for.
- `Group` those documents based on the item id and its complete set of
  alias names, this is done to pick only one alias name for each
  matching part.
- `Group` all the documents by the item id, and accumulate the alias
  names for each part of the item.
- Now we are interested in those items which need be built by a **subset**
  of parts that we are looking for. So `project` a field to check if an
  item can be selected. An item can be selected only if all its parts
  are a subset of our search array.
- `Match` the items which are valid.

Code:

```
var c = ["p1","b1"];

db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"parts.alternate_names":{$in:c}}},
{$project:{"name":1,"parts":1,"partSize":{$size:"$parts"}}},
{$unwind:"$parts"},
{$project:{"name":1,"parts":1,"temp":"$parts.alternate_names","partSize":1}},
{$unwind:"$parts.alternate_names"},
{$match:{"parts.alternate_names":{$in:c}}},
{$group:{"_id":{"names":"$temp","id":"$_id"},
         "size":{$first:"$partSize"},
         "name":{$first:"$name"},
         "alternate_names":{$first:"$parts.alternate_names"}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id.id",
         "size":{$first:"$size"},
         "name":{$first:"$name"},
         "parts":{$push:{"alternate_names":"$alternate_names"}}}},
{$project:{"name":1,
           "parts":1,
           "valid":{$cond:[{$eq:["$size",{$size:"$parts"}]},true,false]}}},
{$match:{"valid":true}},
{$project:{"name":1,"parts":1}}
])
```

Sample Data:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54b2f28adc64efa8ac8a07da"),
        "name" : "wing",
        "parts" : [
                {
                        "alternate_names" : [
                                "p1",
                                "p2",
                                "p3"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "alternate_names" : [
                                "b1",
                                "b2",
                                "b3"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Sample o/p:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54b2f28adc64efa8ac8a07da"),
        "name" : "wing",
        "parts" : [
                {
                        "alternate_names" : "b1"
                },
                {
                        "alternate_names" : "p1"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try later on to see how well it works. My concern would be that it is too slow. My data set doesn't change very often, so maybe I will simply generate a separate denormalised collection where I can run the $nin query. Thanks