# Query for a list contained in another list in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm fairly new to mongo and while I can manage to do most basic operations with the $in, $or, $all, ect I can't make what I want to work.

I'll basically put a simple form of my problem. Part of my documents are list of number, eg :

```
{_id:1,list:[1,4,3,2]}
{_id:2,list:[1]}
{_id:3,list:[1,3,4,6]}
```

I want a query that given a list(lets call it L), would return me every document where their entire list is in L

for example with the given list L = [1,2,3,4,5] I want document with _id 1 and 2 to be returned. 3 musn't be returned since 6 isn't in L.

"$in" doesn't work because it would also return _id 3 and "$all" doesn't work either because it would only return _id 1.

I then thought of "$where" but I can't seem to find how to bound an external variable to the js code. What I call by that is that for example :

```
var L = [1,2,3,4,5];
db.collections('myCollection').find({$where:function(l){
                                       // return something with the list "l" there
                                   }.bind(null,list)})
```

I tried to bind list to the function as showed up there but to no avail ... 
I'd glady appreciate any hint concerning this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a related question [Check if every element in array matches condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23595023/5106017) with [an answer with a nice approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23622265/5106017) for this scenario. It refers to an array of embedded documents but can be adapted for your scenario like this:

```
db.list.find({ 
    "list" : { $not : { $elemMatch : { $nin : [1,2,3,4,5] } } },
    "list.0" : { $exists: true }
})
```

ie. the list must not have any element that is not in [1,2,3,4,5] and the list must exist with at least 1 element (assuming that's also a requirement).

Comment: Is it possible to write the above query as  MongoDB Criteria Query ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, maybe its Spring Data MongoDB?

Comment: Sorry I don't know I've never used it. You could ask a new question

Comment: Hi I tried your query in Spring and answered the q, if you still need it

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-introduction/)** for this where you can make use of the **[set operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation-set/)** to achieve this, in particular you would need the **[`$setIsSubset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset)** operator which returns true if all elements of the first set appear in the second set, including when the first set equals the second set; i.e. not a strict subset.

For example:

```
var L = [1,2,3,4,5];
db.collections('myCollection').aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "list": 1,
            "isSubsetofL": {
                "$setIsSubset": [ "$list", L ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "isSubsetofL": true
        }
    }
])
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "list" : [ 
                1, 
                4, 
                3, 
                2
            ],
            "isSubsetofL" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "list" : [ 
                1
            ],
            "isSubsetofL" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```