# Query for a list contained in another list With Spring Data MongoDb Criterias

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to search a list contained another list with Mongodb.

```
{_id:1,list:[1,2,3,4]}
{_id:2,list:[1]}
{_id:3,list:[1,3,4,6]}
```

I' going to search with list of strings. lets say list L =[1,2,3,4,5]

for example with the given list L = [1,2,3,4,5] I want document with _id 1 and 2 to be returned. 3 must not be returned since 6 isn't in L.

I found two solutions

[one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23622265/5188661)

[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189751/query-for-a-list-contained-in-another-list-in-mongodb)

Since I want to use Spring Data MongoDb Criterias, I tried to write the above solution but the code seems to be not working and it returns all the documents. Any idea how to write this mongo query with spring data mongo Criterias

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
List<Integer> l = List.of(1,2,3,4,5); 
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("list").not().elemMatch(new Criteria().nin(l)));
```