# Mongoose get all documents when all embedded documents have property equal to a specific value but ignore the property when it has another value

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following collection of Order model:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff2"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff1"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "buy"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "arrival"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
```

I want to retrieve all the document when **all** the subdocument has a `status` property equal to `reserved` **but if it is equal to `remove` no problem**, so when I run the query I must get:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff2"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff1"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7fef"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff3"),
                        "status" : "reserved"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5852483a3e8a0d00bb7ff0"),
                        "status" : "remove"
                }
        ],
        "status" : "reserved",
}
```

My current query which is:

```
Order.find( { items: { $not: { $elemMatch: {status:{$ne: 'reserved' } }} } } )
```

Retrieve the documents when all the embedded documents `status` property equal to `reserved`.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Try $nin:['reserved', 'remove'] instead of $ne

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23595023/2683814

Comment: @Veeram thank you, this  $nin:['reserved', 'remove'] retrieve even the ones that contain all items with a `status` equal to `remove`