# Get documents if every document on an Array of Embedded Documents matches a condition

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this document structure:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5b67f78681b1ac90a0106355",
    "nrc": "22652"
    "schedules": [
      {
        "time_ini": "1600",
        "time_fin": "1850",
        "classroom": ".NOREQ",
        "L": null,
        "M": "M",
        "I": null,
        "J": null,
        "V": null,
        "S": null,
        "D": null,
        "date_ini": "06-AUG-18",
        "date_fin": "24-NOV-18"
      },
      {
        "time_ini": "1900",
        "time_fin": "2150",
        "classroom": ".NOREQ",
        "L": null,
        "M": "M",
        "I": null,
        "J": null,
        "V": null,
        "S": null,
        "D": null,
        "date_ini": "06-AUG-18",
        "date_fin": "24-NOV-18"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5b67f79b81b1ac90a0106f0b",
    "nrc": "11567",
    "schedules": [
      {
        "time_ini": "0930",
        "time_fin": "1120",
        "classroom": ".ML_608",
        "L": null,
        "M": "M",
        "I": null,
        "J": null,
        "V": null,
        "S": null,
        "D": null,
        "date_ini": "03-JUL-18",
        "date_fin": "24-NOV-18"
      },
      {
        "time_ini": "1400",
        "time_fin": "1550",
        "classroom": ".ML_608",
        "L": null,
        "M": null,
        "I": null,
        "J": null,
        "V": "V",
        "S": null,
        "D": null,
        "date_ini": "03-JUL-18",
        "date_fin": "24-NOV-18"
      },
      {
        "time_ini": "1000",
        "time_fin": "1150",
        "classroom": ".NOREQ",
        "L": null,
        "M": null,
        "I": null,
        "J": null,
        "V": null,
        "S": "S",
        "D": null,
        "date_ini": "03-JUL-18",
        "date_fin": "24-NOV-18"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I wanna find all documents that match a specific day and only this day on the schedules. As example, I wanna get the documents that only have value on `M` property for every element in `schedules` array, so I tried:

```
db.classes.find({
    "schedules": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "L": null,
            "I": null,
            "J": null,
            "V": null,
            "S": null
        }
    }
})
```

But with this query I will get both documents because the second one have at least one element on the array that also match the condition. But I just wanna get the first one.

Basically, I'm looking `$elemMatch` to get documents that contain the schedules array with all it's elements matching the criteria.

Thank you.

Comment: that means you want to filter array? what should be the expected output?

Comment: The expected output should be only the first document.

Comment: Try `db.classes.find({"schedules":{"$not":{"$elemMatch":{"M":{$ne:"M"l}}}}})`. Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595023/check-if-every-element-in-array-matches-condition

Comment: Does not works. It also finds documents that have "M" and another properties (eg. "L") set as not null. I want only "M" to be not null

Comment: Okay. Change the query to include all the other fields then. Soemthing like `{L:{$ne:null}, I:{$ne:null} ...` so on inside elemMatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer using `$nor`:

```
db.classes.find({
    "schedules.M": "M",
    "$nor" : [
        {
            "schedules.L": "L"
        },
        {
            "schedules.I": "I"
        },
        {
            "schedules.J": "J"
        },
        {
            "schedules.V": "V"
        },
        {
            "schedules.S": "S"
        }
    ]
})
```

In `$nor` array I put all days I wanna exclude and outside it all days I wanna include.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get documents which have all the elements in where M has a value.

```
db.classes.find({
  schedules: {
    $all: [{
      $elemMatch: {
        M: {$ne: null},
        L: null,
        I: null,
        J: null,
        V: null,
        S: null,
        D: null
      }
    }]
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks but does not works. It also finds documents that have "M" and another properties (eg. "L") set as not null. I want only "M" to be not null

Comment: In that case require them to be null in the $elemMatch query. Check the updated answer @MillerAndrésTrujilloAchury

Comment: Still not working, happens same as old answer. Thanks but with `$nor` I made it work already. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706972/7420363), I'm waiting to accept it.