# Mongodb (mongoose) condition check is not work as I expect

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following BSON :

```
[
  {
    arr: [
      {
        age: 24
      },
      {
        age: 55
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    arr: [
      {
        age: 12
      },
      {
        age: 14
      },
      {
        age: 17
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    arr: [
      {
        age: 11
      },
      {
        age: 13
      },
      {
        age: 20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I use the below query :

```
db.collection.find({
  "arr": {
    $elemMatch: {
      age: {
        $lt: 15
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "arr.$": 1
})
```

and the result is :

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "arr": [
      {
        "age": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "arr": [
      {
        "age": 11
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My challenge is that I want if all the elements inside each arr array are less than 15 the it returns them and not when one of them are less than 15. So in this case my expectation answer is an empty array as the output as not all the elements of each array has the age value under 15.

I am not sure if I need to use `$elemMatch` in this case. If there is an alternative to do it please let me know. I just want to get the solution as the query result rather than JavaScript manipulations on the post processing.

By the way I used https://mongoplayground.net/ to check the dataset.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your description of what you want.  I think it would help if you provided the specific output you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you Justin. Basically the output should be an empty array because none of the arrays elements have values under 15

Comment: Both the returned arrays have values less than 15.  Do you mean that you want to find all the arrays where every element in the array has a value less than 15, and not at least one element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if every element in array matches condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595023/check-if-every-element-in-array-matches-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
db.collection.find(
  {"arr.age": {$not: {$gt: threshold}}},
  {arr: {$first: "$arr"}} // This part is relevant if you want only the first item of the array, as seen in your example
)
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bQb4i-l7DWS)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```js
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      "arr.age": {
        $lt: 15
      }
    },
    {
      "arr.age": {
        $not: {
          $gt: 14
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rn7HGR_m2Md) for a working example.

This will find only the documents that have all `arr.age` less than 15.

**Note**: only checking for `$not: { $gt: value }` will return documents when you have an empty array i.e `arr:[]`. This will query will prevent that.